# Why isn’t “lutherie” spelled “luthery”?

Tags: etymology, suffixes

It seems to me that most English words similar to *lutherie* (crafting stringed instruments) end in *‑y*.  That is, nouns for professions or activities that are used instead of gerunds with objects.  (That is, *lutherie* is a noun, *crafting* is a gerund, *stringed instruments* is the object.)  For example, *forestry* (managing forests) or *archery* (shooting arrows).

Why does *lutherie* end with *‑ie*?

Comment: For what it's worth, "lutherie" is not listed at all in any of the freely-available online dictionaries, including Merriam-Webster, Dictionary.com, the Online Etymology Dictionary, Oxford Dictionaries, or Cambridge Dictionaries.

Comment: @nohat I have only heard it as *luthier*.

Comment: And what of *luthiery* and *luthierie* both which I've seen, but not in dictionaries? There is a Luthier school called the Roberto-Venn School of Luthiery in Arizona. And possibly *luthierie* used as a noun meaning “a workshop for building stringed instruments”.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an interesting question Matthew Read. I looked up the etymologies, and this is what I got:

> Lutherie: From French luthier, from `luth` (“lute”) , from Old French `lut`
>
> Forestry:from O.Fr. foresterie, from forest.

Both of these came from French, but their spellings are different because "lutherie" is used much less than "forestry". You can't even find "lutherie" in dictionaries. However, "forestry" is used more frequently, and its spelling has been standardized.

Words that are used more have their spelling updated, while not so popular words remain archaic in spelling.

Comment: Fair enough.  +1, will wait on acceptance to see if I get anything else.  Perhaps I'll begin using "luthery" to help it along :P

Comment: Oops! spelt "dictionarie". Your question is growing on my spelling!

Comment: +1 Likewise *archery* is from Old French *archerie*.